# Accessing UINavigationController at Top of Stack

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationitem

[image]
How do I get a reference to the UINavigationController's backBarButtonItem from the UINavigationController at the top of the stack. In some circumstances I want to disable going back until some networking code is complete.

> `self.parentViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.target =
>   self;`
>   `self.parentViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.action =
>   @sel...;`

doesn't work
delegate method

> `- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar
>   shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item`

doesn't work either.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking to disable the back button of the Questions View Controller regardless of where you are in the Nav Controller stack. Or are you looking to intercept the back button being pressed and intervene?

Comment: Intercept. Need to stop back button in some circumstances.

Comment: QuestionVC does not look like part of the Nav Controller stack. Are you just missing the connection from Main VC to tab bar Controller? What are you calling "top of the stack" in your question?

Comment: Yes, there is segue [NOT SHOWN]. My mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer and a recommendation:

The answer: I would recommend you change your MVC model slightly to have a BOOL property in your model that is on or off depending on whether the network activity is done and then use a delegate/protocol adopted by your QuestionsVC that updates the back button setting as that property changes. You would need to add the following in the delegate method in QuestionsVC:

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

I tested it and it works.

The recommendation: It is never recommended to have UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController (only the inverse is recommended). I would adjust accordingly before you get too deep into your project.

Update:
I can understand the need for a mainVC as startup VC with a button to "start" if you will. You are correct that you need a NavController to be able to push/pop VCs and use segues in Storyboard. But that is not the only way to display a sequence of VCs, you can present/dismiss VCs. So in your case:

1- I would delete the first NavController

2- Make the MainVC the starting VC (entry point) by moving the arrow on the left of the NavController to the left of MainVC

3- Disconnect Main VC from TabBar controller (delete that link) because you will not be able to use segues in SB without Nav Controller. You will have to instantiate and present that tab bar Controller.

4- Add a new object file (.m/.h) - a subclass of UITabBarController and change the class of the tabBarController in IB to the name of your subclass. You might have to build/clean or restart xcode if it does not show on the dropdown of the class list in IB.

5- Create an IBAction method in your mainVC and link it to the button in Main VC.

6- In that method (in your Main VC), add the following code:

```
yourTabBarControllerSubClassName*  myTabController= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theTab"];
[self presentViewController:myTabController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

7- Make sure that in your SB that you select the tab bar controller and in the identity inspector, put the SB ID as "theTab" and check "use SB ID".

8- if questions VC or status table VC have a sequence of VCs within each, you can embed each VC in a Nav Controller and that would be ok.

With that the case, you might not need to worry about that back button since it won't exist anymore!

Good luck

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should put it in QuestionsVC since that is the VC in which you want to hide the back button in the navigation item. It should work.

Comment: Ok... Yep, not sure what I was thinking, your answer is correct. And a good recommendation to boot. I embedded MainVC in a UINav so I could push the TabBVC on MainVC. I can't push from something that doesn't have an UINav, that's why it's there. Open to recommendations ;)

Comment: I will edit my answer under recommendation - based on limited knowledge of your project!